# Angular - Material Table, update a single row instead of the entire table (Angular v10)

Tags: angular

I have a simple angular material table in the UI, e.g.

```
status
-------
On Time
Late
Missing
```

However, when I update its value via the UI, all values change to the same value. (HTML)

````
```
<ng-container matColumnDef="sla">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{value}}</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="value= 'On Time'">On Time</button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="value= 'Late'">Late</button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="value= 'Missing'">Missing</button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="value= 'NDR'">NDR</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </td>
</ng-container>
````

(Typescript)

````
export class Status component implements OnInIt, OnDestroy {
    value =  'Late'
}
```

How can I save the value and let it persist, such that I can change it?
````

Comment: It is not clear with the given description. Can you explain any further?

Comment: `How can I save the value and let it persist, such that I can change it?` can you explain it more ? @cluis92

Comment: Basically, when I change the value on the menu, all items change to the same value. For example, I click the dropdown menu and select 'On Time' then all rows update to 'On Time.' I just want to have the single row have it's value changed and not all rows, and have it persisted (i.e. saved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo in this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yubmpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts).

basically, you need to use `element.sla` only so that when you change table column using mat-menu then selected menu item is assigned to `element.sla` and this way you have your table data updated with new selected mat-menu data too!

```
<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="sla">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
       <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{element.sla}}</button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="element.sla= 'On Time'">On Time</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="element.sla = 'Late'">Late</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="element.sla = 'Missing'">Missing</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="element.sla = 'NDR'">NDR</button>
        </mat-menu>
      </td>
</ng-container>
```